# R: Tibble multible conditions

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

Let's say I have a tibble in R that shows which fruit was eaten in which year how many times (n).

---

year -  fruit - n

<dbl> <chr> <int>

.
.
.
2001    Apple 201

2001    Ananas 50

2002    Apple 40

.
.
.

---

In this example I would like to know how to determine how many fruits were eaten in a particular number of years more than a certain amount (let's say 50)?

Comment: I'm upvoting because of the really cute misspelling of "multiple". (It reamined unclear to my reading whether the desired result was the number eaten in a paticular year fisty years in hte future of the cumulative number eaten in the interval of 50 years.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly than this may be what you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> Loading required package: timechange
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

yr = as_date(c(2000-01-01, 2001-01-01, 2002-01-01))

fruits = c("Apple", "Banannas", "Mangos")

eaten = c(1, 51, 200)

sample_data = tibble(years = rep(yr, 3),
                     fruit = rep(fruits, 3),
                     fruits_eaten = rep(eaten, 3))


sample_data |> 
  filter(fruits_eaten > 50) |> 
  group_by(years, fruit)  |> 
  summarise(sum(fruits_eaten))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'years'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#> # Groups:   years [2]
#>   years      fruit    `sum(fruits_eaten)`
#>   <date>     <chr>                  <dbl>
#> 1 1975-06-23 Banannas                 153
#> 2 1975-06-24 Mangos                   600
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>